# Find the value of a function that satisfy $f(x+1)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: functions

Let $f(x+1)=f(x)\cdot f(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. If $f(1)=8$ then find $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$.

I'm trying to find it as below.

\begin{align}
f(1)=f(0+1)=f(0)\cdot f(y)=8\\
f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) = f\left(-\frac{1}{3}+1\right)=f\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\cdot f(y).
\end{align}

Since I can't find $f(y), f(0), f\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)$, now I confused how to find $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$. Any hint to solve that?

Comment: This functional equation seems to have atypo - because what would happen if I have two different values of $y$ for the same $x$? $f(y_2) = f(y_1)$ for all $y$ means the function is constant and hence 8 everywhere

Comment: @Chrystomath: the question you linked is a different one. Notice $f(x+1)$ instead of $f(x+y)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $y=1$, the functional equation becomes
$$f(x+1)=8f(x)$$ for all $x$.In particular, $f(2)=64$. Then with $x=1$, $y=2$, the functional equation becomes
$$ 64=8\cdot64$$
contradcition. No such $f$ exists.

Answer (score 2):

$f(1)=f(0)f(y)$ for all $y$. So $f$ is a constant function but the only contsant functions satifying the hypothesis are $0$ and $1$ so we cannot have $f(1)=8$.